# After update, Cheese doesn't find external webcam? Why?

Tags: webcam

After a resent update to Ubuntu 14.10, I can not use my external webcam with any of the programs for webcams.  It only sees my laptop built-in webcam now.  It use to give me a choose which cam I want to use.  How can I get it to recognize the external webcam? Why can't I choose which webcam to use with Cheese now?

Comment: Does chrome recognise it? Go to http://webcamtoy.com or something?

Comment: webcamtoy shows the option with the USB camera but it doesn't show any picture, it is just black.  It use to show a picture of what ever it was pointed at.

Comment: Works just fine with Chrome, shows a good picture with it.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a bug in Cheese. Take note of the last version of Cheese which worked if you can, and consider [filing a bug against it in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cheese/+filebug).